# jQuery .scrollHeight is not restoring

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, height

I have a slight predicament. I have an element at a fixed height, but then when I hover over it I want it to go to an auto height. I have this working almost perfectly, but the one problem is that when I take the cursor off the element, it stays an auto height. I want it to go back to the fixed height. Anyone able to help? Here's the jQuery.

```
$('#navContainer').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: $(this)[0].scrollHeight+'px'
    }, 400);
    }, function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: 'auto'
    }, 400);
});
```

I've also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNsQT/) of the entire thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your "height: auto" by 80px

```
$('#navContainer').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: $(this)[0].scrollHeight+'px'
    }, 400);
    }, function(){
    $(this).animate({
        height: '80px'
    }, 400);
});
```